# Rails main app paths called from "inside" engine in layout. How to "not" have paths prefixed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Im attempting to create a (mounted) engine on a current rails5 app. All seems to work, controllers, helpers, and models, but the paths in the main app layout are all prefixed with the engine path.

I understand that it is because it being called from within the engine, but My intended idea would be that the engine would be namespaced under its name, and leave the layout paths alone.  This HAS to be done somehow.

Senerio: I have a running app.  at localhost:3000.  I "install" this new engine named "Edu". It runs perfectly at localhost:3000/edu/MODEL/ID etc...

but now the application.haml layout paths (i.e. dashboard_url ) are all generated to localhost:3000/edu/dashboard.

I can mount it to "/" and all is good, but I like the idea of the prefix in the url, not sure of the benefits just yet.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Edu::Engine, at: "/education"
  ...
  ...





# application_controller.rb
class Edu::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  end



#engine.rb
module Edu
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Edu
  end
 end
```

These are the guides I have been following.

Thanks for any help

https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2015/10/15/rails-mountable-engines/
https://gist.github.com/beneggett/3098702